# What is '!!user' used for? Whats the result of this line?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to craete angular route guard in my app. I found this code but don't understand why we map `user` to `!!user`. What's the purpose of `map(user => !!user)` line?

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

      return this.auth.user.pipe()
           take(1),
           map(user => !!user),
           tap(loggedIn => {
             if (!loggedIn) {
               console.log('access denied')
               this.router.navigate(['/login']);
             }
         })
    )
```

Comment: actualy in this case you can also use something like this `map(Boolean)` works the same way buts even shorter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!!` is a common way to cast something to a boolean.

By applying the NOT operator (`!`) twice in the `map()` function, it maps the user to a boolean which is then used as `loggedIn` which is used in the `tap()` function.

Likely the user is supposed to be an object with userdata (which has a truthy value).

I also assume that if you are not logged in, the user will be `null` or `undefined` (which has a falsy value).